# How to get all tablespaces that a table belongs to in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, tablespace

I know how to get ONE tablespace that a table belongs to:

```
select table_name,tablespace_name from dba_tables where owner = 'OWNER'
order by table_name;
```

This query returns

```
TABLE_NAME | TABLESPACE_NAME
 ----------------------------
 TABLE1     | TABLESPACE_A
 TABLE2     | TABLESPACE_A
 TABLE3     | TABLESPACE_B
```

However, this only returns ONE of the tablespaces that each table belongs to.  I know, for example, that all tables are also part of the USERS tablespace, but the above query does not show that, it only shows ONE tablespace per table.

So how do I see ALL the tablespaces that a table belongs to, including the USERS tablespace?

Comment: How do you "know" that all tables belong to `USERS` tablespace?

Comment: A table (or specific table partition, LOB segment, or index) can only belong to one tablespace. They _can't_ be split across multiple tablespaces. If `DBA_TABLES` says that `TABLE3` is in `TABLESPACE_B`, then that is the only place it exists. If the table contains LOB segments (which can have their own storage clause) then it is possible they could exist somewhere else, but that would be tracked under a different view like DBA_SEGMENTS.

Comment: @mathguy Because for example, if I do `select default_tablespace from dba_users where username = 'USER1'`, it returns USERS.  But I know that USER1 has access to tables in TABLESPACE_A and TABLESPACE_B, because he can select from them. Unless I am checking for what tablespaces a user has access to incorrectly?

Comment: Do you understand the word "default"? A user may be granted space on more than one tablespace. When he creates a table, if he does not specify a tablespace explicitly, then his default tablespace will be used. That doesn't mean that **all** his tables must belong to the default (if he has been granted space on other tablespaces as well), he just needs to include the non-default tablespace explicitly when he creates the table.

Comment: @mathguy I thought that must be the case as well, but whenever I google "how to see all tablespaces belonging to a user", it is suggested to query dba_users, the default_tablespace column.  Do you have a better suggestion for looking up all tablespaces belonging to a user?

Comment: That is a different question. In your original question you asked about tablespaces used by a (single) table. Now you are asking about tablespaces belonging to a **user**. Which one do you need? And also, do you want to know what tablespaces a user has access to (even the ones he has not yet used for anything), or only those he has in fact used already? All these questions can be answered, but you need to ask a very clear and precise question.

Comment: I'm only responding to your own statements and questions. You are the one who mentioned that users can have more than one tablespace. I am asking about tables having more than one tablespace. If you feel the two topics are related, please feel free to write an answer explaining that.

Comment: No, you brought up "user" into the discussion about "tables". You said that you "know" that all tables use the `USERS` tablespace, because you can see that the **user** has default tablespace `USERS`. What does that have to do with anything? What you "know" is just plain wrong.

Comment: Obviously it's possible for none of a user's objects to be in the default tablespace, so querying DBA_USERS won't help. If you are licensed for partitioning then each partition or subpartition could be in a different tablespace. Probably DBA_SEGMENTS would be a better place to start.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thank you for your suggestion.  `When I do select segment_name, tablespace_name from dba_segments`, it shows me the same results as when I query dba_tables, which is one tablespace per table. I need to see all the tablespaces that are assigned to a table.

Comment: @mathguy if you feel that something in my question is wrong, please feel free to write an answer explaining that in detail, and then I can upvote your answer.

Comment: _"all the tablespaces that are assigned to a table"_  As has been explained multiple times in this thread, unless the table is partitioned or there are lob segments, _there is no concept_ of "all the tablespaces that are assigned to a table".  With the aformentioned exceptions, a given table can belong to exactly _one_ tablespace - no more, no less.

Comment: @EdStevens it may have been explained many times in this thread, but no on has provided an answer.  This question remains unanswered.  If you would like to post an answer, I could upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here it is:

The entire concept of "all the tablespaces that are assigned to a table" is a nullity.  A table can belong to one and only one tablespace.

```
spo demo.log
select owner,
       segment_name,
       segment_type,
       tablespace_name
from dba_segments
order by owner,
         segment_name,
         segment_type,
         tablespace_name
;
spo off
edit demo.log
```